ProxyChains is not working. "ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)"
What could be wrong here:

I’ve configured my proxychains.conf file to use dynamic_chain with several proxy IPs, and I set it to dynamic_dns as well. However, when I check my IP through an IP lookup, it remains unchanged, showing my real IP instead of one of the proxies.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Added multiple IP addresses in proxychains.conf and verified that they are valid.
Set dynamic_chain and made sure it’s not using strict_chain.
Confirmed that proxychains is running and that the application is being launched through it.

Despite these steps, my IP doesn’t change. Is there anything I might be missing, or additional troubleshooting steps I should try?
